# Stop events in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Is it possible to stop/suspend raised events in WPF? I want to stop events like SizeChanged, LocationChanged, MouseDown, when my window touches a screen side.

For now on I cannot modify window dimensions, because somehow other events overwrites the values.

**EDIT** I've discovered, that my problem is caused by raised events which overwrites my window object (i guess so), because when I've printed window dimensions in all the events, it occurred that after change other event causes setting original dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

To unsubscribed from an event just type this in the place where you want to stop.

eg: SizeChanged;

```
this.SizeChanged -= MethodName;
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot suspend firing of events. You can either unsubscribe using `EventHandlers`similar to subscribing them:

```
object.someEventHandler -= someMethodOrDelegate
```

or you can suppress the bubbling up/tunneling down of event based on special condition:

```
private void SomeEventHappened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(someCondition)
          e.Handled = true;
    else
          DoSomeWork();
}
```

As per your edit on question and your comments, as far as I understood you have events that change window dimensions, and these prevent you from resizing window manually. Moreover, your eventhandlers are not WPF originated (they use `EventArgs` instead of `RoutedEventArgs`). If I understood correctly, a solution may be having a class-scoped (or `internal`, based on your needs) boolean variable that holds whether to allow/overwrite dimensions or not:

```
bool allowManualResize = false;
```

And then when you are doing size modifications manually, you set this variable to `true`:

```
private void SomeManualSizingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     allowManualResize = true;
     ....
```

After these, you can check for this value in your events that override your new values:

```
private void SomeUpperLevelResizeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Check if resizing is allowed,
   if(!allowManualResize)
   {
       // do your default things here
   ....
```

Of course you need to find a suitable location to set `allowManualResize` to false so that future firings are not suppressed.

Comment: In this example, what exactly will be handled if I set e.Handled = true? It only stops SomeEventHappened?

Comment: It will prevent the future firing of this event on any level of your UI hierarcy. Bubbling and tunneling events fire on different levels, and when you set its `handled` property to true, it will not fire for that particular event. Of course  if the same event happens in the future, it will pop again.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my events get EventArgs, not RoutedEventArgs.